# Unity3d LoadFromCacheOrDownload downloads existing bundle

Tags: unity-game-engine

For downloading bundles I'm using LoadFromCacheOrDownload. It's works fine, but when I'm trying load bundle from cache, it start downloads bundle with same version again.
I'm look at Unity cache folder and found cached bundle(by resources name), but it still want to downlaod bundle.

Comment: Is the version parameter the same each call?

Comment: @AndrewGriffin, yes, the version parameter same for each call